# Interpreting the boundary conditions of a Dirichlet Problem in an annulus

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

This exercise deal with the equation $\Delta u=0$ in polar coordinates. Suppose the inner side of the annulus $D=\{(r,\theta)\,:\,r_{0}\leq r\leq 1\,;\, 0\leq\theta<2\pi \}$ is insulated and the outer side  is held at temperature $u(1,\theta)=f(\theta)$.

My problem is to interpretate this informations. I think "inner side insulated" means $u_{\theta}(r_{0},\theta)=0$. So, I only have the boundary conditions: $u_{\theta}(r_{0},\theta)=0$ and $u(1,\theta)=f(\theta)$. Don't I need two more boundary conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two boundaries in an annulus. Visually you have

[image]

> My problem is to interpretate this informations. I think "inner side
>   insulated" means uθ(r0,θ)=0. So, I only have the boundary conditions:
>   uθ(r0,θ)=0 and u(1,θ)=f(θ).

insulated for the heat conduction problem means its a Neumann problem

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}} \tag{1} $$

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,t) = 0 \tag{2}$$
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(L,t) = 0 \tag{3}$$

for your problem if you solve it in annulus

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(r_{0},\theta) = 0 \\ u(1,\theta) = f(\theta) \tag{4} $$

so you're supposed to solve

$$\frac{d^{2}\phi}{dr^{2}} = -\lambda r \tag{5} $$

with those boundary conditions.